# Default value from Union type following defaultProps value in React Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, union-types

I want to make a Dropdown component with two versions, one that can return multiple selected values and one that returns a single selected value. All of that is determined by a single prop which is called `variant`. this variant has union type `single | multiple`. So this is what it looks like:

```js
type MyOption = { label: any; value: any };

type MyDropdownProps =
  | {
      variant?: "single";
      options: [];
      onChange: (values: MyOption) => void;
    }
  | {
      variant?: "multi";
      options: [];
      onChange: (values: MyOption[]) => void;
    };

const MyDropdown = (props: MyDropdownProps) => {
  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(props)}</pre>;
};

const Render = () => {
  return <MyDropdown options={[]} variant="single" onChange={(evt) => {}} />;
};
```

you see this is work correctly if we specify the `variant` prop:
[image: variant="single"]

[image]

my question is what if we don't want to specify the `variant` prop? what if we already specify it from `defaultProps`?

```js
const MyDropdown = (props: MyDropdownProps) => {
  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(props)}</pre>;
};

MyDropdown.defaultProps = {
  variant: "single"
};
```

[image]

You see the `onChange` is not returning the correct data, it returns with `any` type. How do we fix this? I've spent weeks trying to find the answer but still have not found it yet :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your props and component as generic and use the variant type to determine the parameter type for `onChange`.

Since your variant can only be one of two types, I would opt for a simpler Boolean type determined by the presence of a `multiple` prop (just like `<select>`).

```ts
interface MyDropDownProps<Multiple extends Boolean> {
  multiple?: Multiple;
  options: MyOption[];
  onChange: (values: Multiple extends true ? MyOption[] : MyOption) => void;
}
```

You can then define your generic component

```tsx
const MyDropdown = <Multiple extends Boolean>(
  props: MyDropDownProps<Multiple>
) => {
  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(props)}</pre>;
};
```

[image: with multiple]

[image: without multiple]

Comment: wow, I already have tried that, the with `extends` and using ternary operator. I thought it would not work since it's only got `single` option when we try to get the autocomplete for the `variant` prop. Turns out it's work. I guess I'll just try to make it as boolean like `isMulti` so we only just put `isMulti` in the component if we want to try the multiple selection

Comment: haha, yes like the ones that you updated. Thank you man, I'll make it as the answer now

Comment: @FadilNatakusumah yep, since you're basically emulating a `<select>`, I thought it best to adopt the `multiple` attribute in the same way

Answer (score 1):

Consider this example:

```js
import React from 'react'

type MyOption = { label: any; value: any };

type MyDropdownProps =
    {
        options: [];
        onChange: (values: MyOption[] | MyOption) => void;
    };

const MyDropdown = (props: MyDropdownProps) => {
    return <pre>{JSON.stringify(props)}</pre>;
};

const Render = () => {
    return <MyDropdown options={[]} onChange={(evt /* MyOption[] | MyOption */) => { }} />;
};
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/m3XGyW)

If you don't want to specify `variant` property, then, in fact you don't need a union of props. You need a union of `onChange` arguments